# confirm() with <input type="submit"> doesn't cancel

Tags: javascript, html

i have this form action:

```
<form action="https://google.com">
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="submit" onclick="mostra(this, form)">
  </form>
  <script>
    function mostra(that, form) {
      if (form.checkValidity()) {
        if (confirm('Sei sicuro di inviare la richiesta?')) {
          that.disabled = true;
          that.value = 'ok';
          form.submit();
        } else {
          alert("else");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

When the pop up of the `confirm()` method comes out and i click `cancel`, the flow of the code correctly enter in the else, but the form is sent anyway.

I tried to use `<input type="button" onclick="mostra(this,form)">` and it works correctly, so the flow it's different between `ok and cancel`, but the popup of the of the HTML `required` prorperty if the input is empy is never showed. Here, i understand that it's because the form need to be submitted and not just "clicked".

So i think that the first code is better. How i can solve my problem and have the correct flow?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent the `submit` event instead of returning false on `click`

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', mostra)

function mostra(e) {
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    if (confirm('Sei sicuro di inviare la richiesta?')) {
      that.disabled = true;
      that.value = 'porca madonna';
      form.submit();
    } else {
      alert("else");
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com">
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button type "Submit" is inside a form and when the form is submitted the page is reloaded. You need cancel the default action of the event with the preventDefault() method.